# Helm does not delete StatefulSet when release is deleted

Tags: kubernetes, memcached, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the `stable/memcached` Helm chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/memcached)

Creating a new release works as expected. It created a StatefulSet with three pods and a Service. But when deleting the release the StatefulSet is left behind and only the Service is deleted.

`helm list` shows that the release is no longer there.

Is this a bug or a feature and how can I make `helm delete` also delete the StatefulSet?

Answer (score 0):

I just did `helm install stable/memcached` and then deleted the release. The pods did get removed for me, which is the expected behaviour. I'm on kubernetes v1.9.7 and helm v2.10.0-rc.1+gaa98e7e. Presumably there's something preventing deletion of those resources. You could try the delete with `--purge --no-hooks`. There have been [related bugs in previous versions](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2772) so best to check your version. If it's not related to the version then best to work out if the problem is related to some nuance of the install you're doing (presumably you're running a more complex command than simply `helm install stable/memcached`).

Comment: I'm using Helm v2.9.1 and just using that exact command `helm install stable/memcached`. I'll try a different helm version.

Comment: You could also try `helm install stable/keycloak` or `helm install stable/rabbit-hq` to see if you get the same problem with other charts that use Statefulsets.

Comment: Yeah I did try `stable/rabbitmq` and it did the same thing.

Comment: Is it an older k8s version? There have been reports of similar-sounding problems that were sensitive the k8s version - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2908

Comment: Also worth trying in another cluster if you can (e.g. minikube)